# Não estou conseguindo rodar no emulador nem dispositivo a realease do App React Native para Android

Tags: android, react-native

```
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (8240) for package br.edu.utfpr.marvas.benchmark_rn ----------------------------
2023-12-30 12:17:33.265   616-2608  AppOps  system_process  Bad call made by uid 1000. Package "br.edu.utfpr.marvas.benchmark_rn" does not belong to uid -1.
2023-12-30 12:17:33.265   616-2608  AppOps  system_process  noteOperation
java.lang.SecurityException: Specified package "br.edu.utfpr.marvas.benchmark_rn" under uid -1 but it is not
    at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.verifyAndGetBypass(AppOpsService.java:4694)
        at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.noteOperationUnchecked(AppOpsService.java:3453)
        at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.noteOperationImpl(AppOpsService.java:3441)
        at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.-$$Nest$mnoteOperationImpl(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService$CheckOpsDelegateDispatcher.lambda$noteOperation$4(AppOpsService.java:7640)
        at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService$CheckOpsDelegateDispatcher.$r8$lambda$oOwUoG55BBmJ6yiwhp3OAq3tQ30(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService$CheckOpsDelegateDispatcher$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.apply(Unknown Source:32)
        at com.android.server.policy.AppOpsPolicy.noteOperation(AppOpsPolicy.java:227)
        at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService$CheckOpsDelegateDispatcher.noteOperation(AppOpsService.java:7638)
        at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.noteOperation(AppOpsService.java:3425)
        at com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsService$Stub.onTransact(IAppOpsService.java:479)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1280)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1244)
```